# pycharm does not show docstring math correctly?

Tags: python, pycharm, latex, docstring

As the title says, whenever I view docstrings in pycharm I'm not seeing the math correctly even in reading mode, which I would assume should show me the math rather than the 'code' generating the math.

[image]

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this, since it is getting pretty annoying trying to read docstrings for complicated math functions like this.

This is what happens when I convert the .py file to .md

[image]

The file can be read, but the math is still not interpreted. Do I need some special latex plugin for this?

When I convert it to .rst I get the following:

[image]

So clearly that format doesn't work at all in pycharm.

Edit2: I have added a Class with a docstring containing math in it as well, as requested.

```
class FullyConnectedTensorProduct(TensorProduct):
    r"""Fully-connected weighted tensor product

    All the possible path allowed by :math:`|l_1 - l_2| \leq l_{out} \leq l_1 + l_2` are made.
    The output is a sum on different paths:

    .. math::

        z_w = \sum_{u,v} w_{uvw} x_u \otimes y_v + \cdots \text{other paths}

    where :math:`u,v,w` are the indices of the multiplicities.

    Parameters
    ----------
    irreps_in1 : `Irreps`
        representation of the first input

    irreps_in2 : `Irreps`
        representation of the second input

    irreps_out : `Irreps`
        representation of the output

    normalization : {'component', 'norm'}
        see `TensorProduct`

    internal_weights : bool
        see `TensorProduct`

    shared_weights : bool
        see `TensorProduct`
    """
```

Comment: This looks like sphinx directives. pycharm can't parse/show these correctly, certainly not within a py file and certainly not without plugins.

Comment: You can, however, try to extract these to a separate `.md` or `.rst` file, then Pycharm's built-in previewer (top right corner) might be able to render the latex part

Comment: I'm just wondering what the purpose of reading mode is if it isn't to show these kinds of things when viewing read-only source files.
.md files also doesn't show the math correctly and .rst files appear to not show anything at all. So I guess pycharm just doesn't support this even though they claim to do:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/restructured-text.html#f301f687
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7124-restructuredtext

Comment: You keep confusing between parsing and rendering rst/markdown and reading and parsing latex.

Comment: That is probably true, and I'm still not sure what the difference is to be honest. I guess what I want is for some way to have pycharm parse latex in the docstrings or how would you frame it?
I have added a few pictures to the original post of what it looks like when I convert a file from .py to .md or .rst

Comment: Can you edit the question to include an example docstring besides the screenshots? The feature you are asking for does work.

Comment: I have added a docstring to the example above. You say these kinds of docstrings work for you? Did you have to do anything special to get the math interpreted correctly?

Comment: @Tue you could have pinged me in the comments (I forgot to follow the thread and only saw the edit now). Yes, this can be done but it's a lengthy explanation. There's an additional problem, I don't have Tensorflow installed. I could show this working using the math equation and standard library classes. I have to ask: what do you normally use the equations in the docstrings for? Do you generate directly from the docstrings to Latex, and how?

Comment: @bad_coder Sorry, didn't know that I could tag people like that on stackoverflow, I'm not that experienced on this site. My typical usecase is that I use some function from another library and I wish to read the docstring for this function/class or directly see what the function does. So normally I just ctrl+click on the function in pycharm and follow it to the source file and read the source file directly. However, this is where I end up seeing this unformatted latex math which makes the docstring hard to read. 
If there is a smarter way to do this kind of thing I'm very open to suggestions.

Comment: @Tue ok, I'll try to write an answer later this week (I'm not making any promises about when exactly just because it's a lengthy time-consuming answer to write).